# Looking for examples of bayesian modelling and smoothing in a GIS

Tags: modelling

I am looking to assemble clear examples of Bayesian modelling / smoothing in a GIS. I have yet to see GIS being used to conduct Bayesian style analytical models and would like to see what is currently out there. I am interested in both the application of Bayesian modelling and its current state of inclusion in traditional and/or non-proprietary (opensource) software.

At the moment I am very interested in Bayesian modelling for transportation planning, specifically transit ridership and modal split/share estimations.

Comment: Are you familiar with [GeoBUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/winbugs/geobugs.shtml)?

Comment: Are you familar with it enough to post a useful example? Looks interesting.

Comment: Alittle focus would be helpful. What fields are you interested in (social sciences, environmental sciences?) This will also partly dictate the software environments, as not many tools handle both raster and vector data.

Comment: @AndyW - Transportation mainly... with background in multiple criteria decision analysis and predictive modelling. Added to my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand Arc 10.1 includes Empirical Bayesian Kriging (EBK) with the Geostatistical Analyst.  See the attached links for more detail.

[EBK thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/36449-What-s-new-with-Geostatistical-Analyst-10.1)

[EBK info](http://betablogs.esri.com/beta/arcgis/2011/08/25/empirical-bayesian-kriging/)

Edit:

Additional ArcGIS algorithms using Bayesian Statistics and/or decision rules

[Maximum Likelihood](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000q9000000.htm)

[Class Probability](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000p6000000.htm)